# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized - WCF basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding, unauthorized

I get this error when I want to execute a method on my service with wcfstorm client.

I tried so many different settings and I can't get it to work. If I switch to Transport security I get another error.. It worked perfectly with wsHttpBinding but customer wants basicHttpBinding because of PHP compatibility. I need a custom user authentication class to authenticate users against my sql database..

web.config

```
  <services>
  <service name="e3kConnector.E3KConnectorService" behaviorConfiguration="basicHttpBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpEndpoint"
      contract="e3kConnector.e3kConnectorService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="e3kConnector.App_Data.Security.CustomUserNameValidator,e3kConnector" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="e3kConnector.App_Data.Security.AuthorizationPolicy, e3kConnector" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```